# GKE - Quotas - In-use IP addresses global exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Recently we've attempted to a add a new ingress and encountered this error.

```
QUOTA_EXCEEDED - Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded.  Limit: 8.0 globally.
```

Heading over to the IAM -> Quota page we observed that 'In-use IP addresses global' was indeed 8 out of 8.

Next we wanted to know where we were using these IP addresses.  Heading over to VPC network -> External IP addresses only 6 were listed; 4 assigned to k8s forwarding rules and 2 assigned to our two k8s nodes.

Our question; where are the other to 'In-use IP addresses global' being consumed?

Comment: Try the command `gcloud compute addresses list`.

Comment: running `gcloud compute addresses list` only revealed 4 public addresses.  I understand there are 2 in use on the nodes, for some reason those are not listed.  still this only accounts for 6 out of the 8.

Comment: Do you have more than one project? If yes, check each one. Instead of us guessing, post details about your account, and now it is structured. Include the services that you are using, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @johnhanley reported that would allow you to see [in-use IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list).

```
gcloud compute addresses list --global
```

Check also [External IP addresses quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#external_ip_addresses), in order to understand how these limits work.

Please be aware of the starred section:

> Note: If the same IP address is assigned to more than one forwarding rule, Google Cloud counts and adds each usage of the address towards the IN_USE_ADDRESSES quota rather than a unique count of IP address objects that are used.

To view the current quota limits, from Google Cloud Console navigate to :

> IAM & Admin -> Quotas -> Service (Compute Engine API) -> Metric(In-use
> IP addresses)

You can filter by the location preferred if you choose to. You can request to [increase the quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#request_quotas), please be sure to provide a justification for the number you decide to enter for the new quota.

Comment: running `gcloud compute addresses list` only revealed 4 public addresses. I understand there are 2 in use on the nodes, for some reason those are not listed. still this only accounts for 6 out of the 8.

Comment: Excuse me , I forgot to mention the forwarding rules note. I added into my answer.